# connected component labelling in arabic charackters

Tags: python, arabic, opencv

how to segmentation **Arabic characters[arabic charackter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWDQB.png)** using connected component labeling algorithm (cv2.connectedcomponent) like image above, i want the image as 1 image not 2 image after segmentation with connected component

Comment: What do you mean by this, "i want the image as 1 image not 2 image after segmentation with connected component"?

Comment: i mean, afeter use connected component labelling, 2 object read as 1 object, because arabic charackter is unique, 1 charackter can have 2 or more object like this [link](https://docplayer.info/docs-images/62/47188773/images/7-1.jpg) in this image called 'ba' this charackter have 2 object, if i use cv2.connectedcomponent this image can segment to 2 object, but i want segment to 1 object

Comment: You will need to do some post-processing to do this because cv2.connectdecomponenet is a simple segmentation algorithm based on pixel changes. However, it isn't an algorithm trained to detect Arabic characters and segment accordingly.

I would suggest looking into Deep Learning methods that solve character segmentation. Here is a good example that I have found: https://github.com/AmrHendy/Arabic-Handwritten-Images-Recognition/blob/master/Arabic_Handwritten_Recognition.ipynb

Comment: thank you your response, I'll check it right now

Comment: ah, but if for recognition 1 charackter i use SVM classification and its work, but in implementation, i send image contain 2 or more charackter and use connected component to split charackter and then recognize it